# KDE Plasma 5 taskbar dissappears on external monitors

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, taskbar, kde, plasma-tv

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-28-generic and Plasma 5.6.5

I am mostly docked with two external displays, and I use all three with the Laptop one as primary.
I have a customized taskbar for each monitor but sometimes (not every time) when I reboot, one or both of the external monitors goes blank. When I enter display configuration to check the status of the blank screen(s), it's/they're enabled. If I disable and re-enable, it/they will come back on, but without the taskbar..

Any clues of what's going on?

If there's no permanent fix; Is there a config file for plasmashell that includes the config for all taskbars that I can backup to reload whenever this happens?